# How to represent view/edit modes with storyboards?

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard

I have an app written in objective c which I am rewriting in swift and cleaning up/modernising at the same time. The app allows recipes to be viewed and edited. As you can see from this section of the storyboard, it currently duplicates the view layout between view mode and edit mode:

[image]

Is there a way I can use a single view in the storyboard to represent the read only view mode and the edit mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done something like this by putting labels and textFields in the same place in storyboard, and set the textFields to be hidden by default.  Then you can toggle the labels and textFields' hidden property (or animate them by changing the alpha property) when the user hits the edit/save button.  Your storyboard will look crazy, but nobody will ever see the overlapping labels/textFields when the app is actually running.  You'll just have to make sure you're always updating the label text to the newly updated textField text as the user is toggling back and forth.

Comment: Thanks, that works. You also inspired me to look at the properties available on a textfield. It looks like the properties can be modified so that it looks like a label. Hopefully I can get away with just using text fields.